# check file exist if file name is unicode in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, unicode, filenames

I have a file in the storage and I can't check it, because the name of the file is unicode. That's why the FileExist function return with false, but the file is exist, it's sure, because when i list it, the file name will show. The file name is a hungarian word.

```
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();


// List files
List<String> fileList = new List<String>(fileStorage.GetFileNames("Informations/*"));

(string file in fileList)
{
    MessageBox.Show("file: " + file);
    // Will appear: "file: Felhasználási Feltételek.html"
}


// Check file: return false
if (fileStorage.FileExists("Informations/Felhasználási Feltételek.html"))  
{
}
```

What is the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the problem:
i copied the file name from windows explorer, i put F2 on the file, ctrl+c and ctrl+v into source code. the file name was correct into code, but when the application was run, the fileName value was wrong and the solution was that i wrote the filename by keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can game the system I guess, by making your "own" FileExists logic, such as:

```
private bool FileExists(string name, List<string> fileList)
{
    foreach (string file in fileList)
    {
        if (file == name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then you can use this to check your file.